# Which Jedi have served in the Rebellion?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, the-rebel-alliance

Besides Luke Skywalker, Kanan Jarrus, Ezra Bridger and Ahsoka Tano, which other Jedi, regardless of whether they were survivors of Order 66 or became one at a later point, served within the Rebellion's ranks during the Galactic Civil War?

Looking for both canon and Legends versions.

**Edit**: ok, just to clarify what would qualify as a Jedi for the answer. Loosely speaking, anyone who follow the ideals of the Jedi philosophy - a practitioner in the ways of the Force, a protector of the galaxy, and an opposer to the dark side - would count.

- Only trained Force users, not aligned with the dark side, would count. They need to be able to consciously control their use of the Force to aid the Rebellion. This excludes Leia
- Members of the Jedi Order of the late Republic would obviously count. However, they need to have survived Order 66 (duh), did not renounce the Jedi ways nor succumbed to the dark side, and become a member of the Rebellion. This excludes the Grand Inquisitor nor Darth Vader, but includes Kanan Jarrus and, in Legends, Rahm Kota. Those who are killed in action after joining the Rebellion also count.
- However, you don't need to be an official member of the order to be counted. You could be opposed to what was wrong with the late order, but as long as you follow the ideals defined above, and identify with them, you are a Jedi *at heart* by the count of this question. This counts Ahsoka Tano, Luke Skywalker and Ezra Bridger among its number. They aren't in the old Jedi Order's roster, but they believe in what the Jedi are meant to be, and follow its ways in that regard. Galen Marek in Legends, when he genuinely turned to the ways of the light, even though he was still a user of dark side powers, would be one. *It's the thought that counts.*

So loosely speaking, that means members of the Rebellion who are trained Force sensitives and genuine good guys.

Comment: You forgot Leia ?

Comment: @Max She's a Force-sensitive, but she's not a Jedi, not until after the Rebellion.

Comment: Tano is technically not a Jedi since she left the order (she even says this in an episode of Rebels)

Comment: Take a look at my edit. I hope the definition doesn't make it too broad. Someone trained in the ways of the Force and is a good guy shouldn't be too ambiguous.

Comment: the question contains "... or became one (jedi) at a later point..." which is the case with Leia (I think).

Comment: @Max But that only happened AFTER the war, so she wasn't a trained Force user of any sort during the Rebellion era.

Comment: Would you consider Anakin Skywalker to be distinct enough from Darth Vader to count? Because he helped the Rebellion's cause for about 10 seconds, and was arguably one of the most important 10 seconds in the entire original trilogy.

Comment: Merge completed. If you like, you can now edit this version of the question to ensure TylerH's answer fits it completely, but please don't invalidate either of the *other* answers with your edit.

Answer (score 10):

### Force-sensitive characters from Episodes IV - VI, Star Wars Rebels, and Rogue One who helped the Rebellion:

- Yoda - Jedi Master, Grand Master of the Jedi Order of The Old Republic, Force Ghost.
- Obi-Wan Kenobi - Jedi Knight, Jedi Master, and Council member of The Old Republic, Force Ghost.
- Luke Skywalker - Jedi trained by Obi-Wan and Yoda.
- Anakin Skywalker (killing the Emperor after he was "saved" from the dark side by Luke, thus becoming Anakin again) - Jedi Knight and member of the Jedi Council (and *tentative* Jedi Master, had he not attacked Mace Windu in the Chancellor's office). Also becomes a Force Ghost after he dies.
- Kanan Jarrus - Jedi Knight who survived Order 66 and was part of a squadron of rebels who work for and then eventually become part of the Rebellion. Kanan trains Ezra in the ways of the Force and the Jedi when Ezra joins their crew. Kanan's spirit later guides Ezra and crew via a giant Loth Wolf while they are on Lothal.
- Ezra Bridger - "Jedi"-in-training; Kanan's padawan.
- Ahsoka Tano - Former Jedi Padawan to Anakin Skywalker. Was expelled from the Order during a trial for murder. Upon being found innocent, the Order reinstated her and declared the trial served as her actual Jedi Trial to become a Knight. However, she left the Order of her own will, so only *tentatively* a Jedi Knight.
- Chirrut Îmwe - One of the "Guardians of the Whills" (monks from the Temple of the Kyber). At several times during the events of Rogue One, Chirrut helped the main characters in their ultimate efforts to steal the technical plans to the Death Star for the Rebellion. While not trained in the ways of the Force like a Jedi, he is Force sensitive and utilizes it many times in combat (good thing, too, as he is completely blind in both eyes).

---

### Unknowns/Caveats/Honorable Mentions from Episodes IV - VI, Rebels, and Rogue One:

---

- Darth Maul - The Zabrak who just can't die* somehow survives his last encounter with the Empire/Sidious & Co. in order to aid Ezra in retrieving a Sith datacron on Mustafar. While not really working "against the Dark Side", he is aiding Ezra, Kanan, and Ahsoka in combating the three Inquisitors in pursuit.

  * He ultimately dies at the hands of Obi-Wan in the deserts of Tatooine.
- Grand Inquisitor - While initially aligned with the Empire and therefore against the eponymous Rebels in Star Wars Rebels, late in season 2, inside a Jedi temple on Lothal, Kanan encounters a training room filled with Temple Guardians, one of whom speaks to Kanan, and reveals he is the Grand Inquisitor, and was once a Jedi Knight of the Jedi Order, like Kanan. He agrees to stall the Inquisitors who are pursuing Kanan, thus helping Kanan and, by extension, the Rebellion. Normally he's a bad guy, but in this moment he is a force user who is aligned against the dark side.
- Princess/General Leia Organa - Sister of Luke Skywalker and daughter of Anakin Skywalker. Had a tenuous awareness, at best, of her connection to the Force during Episodes IV - VI; didn't really become fleshed out as a Force-user until she appeared in Legends novels, and then displayed a single, bizarrely masterful use of The Force in Episode VIII, before being officially retconned in Episode IX as having received training as a Jedi by Luke Skywalker shortly after the events of Episode VI).

Comment: @Ellesedil I'll merge the two questions; that way, this answer will appear on the one that's still open.

Comment: In Legends, there is also [Rahm Kota](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rahm_Kota) and [Galen Marek](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galen_Marek). And while [X2](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/X2) didn't become a Jedi himself until after the war, he is a clone of Jedi, so maybe he counts.

Comment: In Legends, there's also Kyle Katarn, and many pilots were force sensitive, like Keyan Farlander.

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm honestly surprised that you Overlooked one very important Jedi that Fits all of your Criteria though Technically he wasn't an official member of the Rebellion he did fight and die for it and without him the Empire could never have been overthrown, if you haven't yet guessed the person I'm talking about is Obi-Wan (Ben) Kenobi. 
He fought for the rebellion when he faced Vader on the Death Star and if he hadn't told Luke to use the Force on his attack run then the Death Star wouldn't have been destroyed.

Comment: Lol I remember him alright, I just couldn't decide if he can be considered to have directly served the Rebellion...I guess you're right lol

Comment: @thegreatjedi: He helped rescue Leia from the Death Star, which led to the plans for the Death Star being secured in Rebel hands. That's pretty significant and directly affected the Rebellion.

Answer (score 2):

Wife of Luke [Mara Jade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mara_Jade), Jedi Master

[Kyle Katarn](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kyle_Katarn), Jedi Master

Comment: AFAIK, Mara Jade was on the opposite side of the rebellion during the Galactic Civil War.

Comment: Yup, Mara Jade didn't join the Rebellion until long after it became the New Republic. And while Kyle Katarn did help the Rebellion by stealing the Death Star plans and shutting down the Dark Trooper project, he didn't become a Jedi until after the war.

Answer (score 0):

Ferus Olin lead the resistance group called the 11. He helped to form the rebellion, as well as to supply it with weapons and troops, wounded Darth Vader several times and died fighting him to allow Leia to escape. He did leave the jedi before order 66 but took up their ways again. Here are a few others: Obi-Wan Kenobi, Kyle Katarn, Starkiller (Galen Marek's clone), Rahm Kota, several jedi gathered by Ferus, as well as several others.

Answer (score 0):

Tyneir Renz was a Jedi Knight who left the temple to study archaeology and anthropology. He married and had two children, violating the Jedi Code, however on the outbreak of the Clone Wars he returned to the Jedi Order and took the rank of Colonel in the Grand Army of the Republic. Escaping Order 66 at the end of the Clone Wars, he joined the Rebel Alliance, retaining his previous rank. In the service of the Alliance, he used his archaeological skills to recover artefacts confiscated by the Empire and return them to their original people, gaining their support for the Rebellion in return.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tyneir_Renz