# How many Jedi have helped the Rebel Alliance?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, the-rebel-alliance

From the rise of the Galactic Empire in 19 BBY to the death of the Emperor in 4 ABY, which known Jedi has the Alliance to Restore the Republic and its predecessors benefited off of?

This includes any Jedi who has directly  helped the Alliance in any capacity or form, such as but not limited to formal members, non-members but friends nonetheless who has offered assistance before, or any who lent their services whether as a favour or as part of a transaction/deal of any sort.

I would like to know both Disney Canon and Legends versions. Also, the term Jedi here is loosely defined as a catch-all for any Force user who is aligned with the good guys and opposed to the dark side - "part-time" Jedi like Ahsoka would qualify.

**Edit**: Well...I didn't realise I asked this before. Request to reopen this question as the answer here is more complete. I want to delete the other one (seems the wording for the older question is more convoluted too).

Comment: You've already asked this question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121928/which-jedi-have-served-in-the-rebellion They are so similar in scope that I think separate ones are uncalled for.

Comment: Re your edit: if you've asked the same question twice and received a good answer on the duplicate, the correct course of action is to **merge** the two questions, thus migrating the answer(s) on the duplicate to the original. I'll do this now.